How can I create a page movement motion similar to native web using React and framer motion?
I am building an application using React (SPA) based on Vite and react-router-dom. This project is a project that enters the web view.
Therefore, like in an application, when moving a page (push), I want to implement an animation where the page moves from left to right when going to the previous page (pop), such as going back from right to left.
I've tried it myself, but it's not working. Also, I know that when implementing backtracking, I need to take a snapshot (caching) of the page that already exists. How should I do this?
Or, if you have any good references, please let me know.
thank you
I've tried it myself, but it's not working.
